# How can i use python2 and python3 in geany for different files without having to change it every time?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

In build commands it shows python2 currently and i can manually change to python3 but im wondering if i could input bot hand have an option to choose before running it?

Answer (score 1):

Use one of these two lines as the initial line of your source code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2

#! /usr/bin/env python3
```

If geany, or any other editor, does not appropriately adapt to the shebang, you may want to feature request that it does. (And do please post a response about whether shebang has the desired effect.)